# How do I return filename on label after selected in cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, label, return, filenames, filechooser

I'm working on an encrypting application, and I have implemented a file chooser. After I select the file, I want to be able to return the filename onto a label right next to the "choose file" button. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At some point, you probably get an NSString path to the file. The following line will extract the file name, inclusive of its extension:

```
NSString *fileName = [pathAsNSString lastPathComponent];
```

If want to strip the extension, add this line:

```
[fileName stringByDeletingPathExtension];
```

(I got this info from the NSString Class Reference, in the section called "Working with Paths
.")

Or is your path in the form of an NSURL/CFURL? Then you can get an NSString path from it, by calling either relativePath or absolutePath on the url, depending on how you got the path. (Again, this info is in the NSURL Class Reference.)

Then use "fileName" to set the label's text property. The exact code for doing this depends on the class you've used for the label. Once more, that class's Class Reference will supply you with the info you need.